# Change no results behavior of the result of a link generated from a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I created a view that displays links to all of the terms in one of my vocabularies, which was easy enough, but now I am having trouble with what happens when one of those links is clicked.  By default, it will show all content tagged with those terms, which is right, but I want to change the no results behavior when there is not content tagged with a term.

I'm confused as to where I would change the no results behavior for this, do I have to create a separate view, or is this to be done in the view of listing taxonomy terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!  So after hours of research and playing around in my views, I figured out that the problem was I was having the individual links go to the Taxonomy page for that term.  I turned that off and re-wrote the results of each link to be the term: Name instead of that term's url alias.  I got rid of all my URL aliases for the terms.  I also added a second view that used the term and node relationship and a term: Name contextual filter, and added the custom no results behavior I wanted on that view.

In the end my URLs are not as clean since spaces and ampersands are converted to html escape characters, like "%26", but at least I have a no results behavior I want.